# ReactJS - массив и его модификация через props

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Не понимаю как сделать сортировку книг. В родительском блоке создал массив со всеми данными книгами, а дальше не понимаю как по нажатию на кнопки (всего их 4 и каждая модифицирует массив по своему: одна отображает его полностью, вторая сортирует по рейтингу, третья по популярности и четвертая выводит только бесплатные книги) в одном child-компоненте, передавать этот модифицированный массив в другой child-компонент. 
Я новичок в этом деле и не понимаю пока как это реализовать...

Comment: Если ты добавишь код с попытками своей реализации, будет проще помочь тебе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как кода вы не привели в вопросе, то и ответ будет основан на рекомендациях с минимумом кода. Итак, предположим, что есть родительский компонент, где есть массив со всеми книгами (банальный и простой пример, `allBooks` - все книги (оригинальный массив), `filteredBooks` - отфильтрованный массив книг, предположим, что через пропсу сюда попадает весь список книг):

```
const books = [
  { ID: 1, Name: 'One', Author: 'Remark' },
  { ID: 2, Name: 'Two', Author: 'Burunov' },
  { ID: 3, Name: 'Three', Author: 'Romanov' },              
],
```

Предположим, что у нас есть некий набор книг, где лежат объекты, описывающие книги и этот массив передается через пропсу `books` в родительский компонент, ну либо внутри `componentDidMount` загружается откуда, то, но смыл простой, мы проинициализируем наши переменные в стейте родителя:

```
class ParrentComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      allBooks: props.books,
      filteredBooks: props.books, // изначально можно пустой массив `[]`
    }

    // some code here...

  }

  // some code here...

}
```

Предположим, что у нас есть свои методы фильтрации, можно и справочник завести (в случае с Redux было бы удобнее), и эти методы также будут лежать в родительском компоненте, для примера напишу пару штук:

```
showAllBooks() {
  const { allBooks } = this.state;
  this.setState({ filteredBooks: allBooks });
}

filterByName(name) {
  const { allBooks } = this.state;
  const filteredBooks = allBooks.filter(book => book.Name === name)
  this.setState({ filteredBooks });
}

filterByAuthor(author) {
  const { allBooks } = this.state;
  const filteredBooks = allBooks.filter(book => book.Author === author)
  this.setState({ filteredBooks });
}
```

Обрашу ваше внимание на то, что метод [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) создаёт новый массив со всеми элементами, прошедшими проверку, задаваемую в передаваемой функции, что является безопасным подходом и не вызовет мутации состояния.

Теперь перейдем к вашим чаилд компонентам. Первый, как я понимаю там кнопки с *фильтрами*, точнее по нажатию на кнопки будет происходить отображение того или иного массива. Передадим в этот чаилд компонент ссылки на наши методы. Второй - будет содержать пропсу с отфильтрованным списком.

```
<ChildWithButtons
  showAllBooks={this.showAllBooks}
  filterByName={this.filterByName}
  filterByAuthor={this.filterByAuthor}
/>

<ChildWithFilteredBooks
  filteredBooks={this.state.filteredBooks}
/>
```

Внутри этого компонента навесим обработчкик кликов на кнопки, для примера кусочек из рендера и обработка для одной кнопки (для других по подобию):

```
<button onClick={this.filterByName}>Filter by name</button>
```

в этом же компоненте будет свой обработчик этого клика и вызов из него метода фильтрации через пропсу.

```
filterByName(event) {
  const name = 'One'; // для примера будет такое имя, его можно брать откуда угодно
  this.props.filterByName(name); // вызовем метод фильтрации из пропсы
}
```

После клика по кнопке вызовется метод из пропсы, отфильтруется массив и обновится второй чаилд компонент, который использует отфильтрованный массив, так как обновится его пропса `filteredBooks`. Вот так, посредством `props` из одного родительского компонента можно произвести общение между двумя его дочерними компонентами. Обратите внимание, что оригинальный массив `allBooks` мы не меняем, а используем его как источник для фильтрации. Не забываем про байндинги внутри конструктора, если вдруг нужен `this`, а он нужен.

Также будет полезно почитать:

- [React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)
- [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)
- [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: я передаю в дочерний компонент
<General filteredBooks={this.state.filteredBooks} />

В дочернем пишу 
<div className="general">
    {this.props.filteredBooks.map((index, key) =>

но у меня вылазиет ошибка {
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at General.render
}

Comment: Я создал массив const books = [
 {
  ID: 1,
  Name: 'Jewels of Nizam',
  Author: 'by Geeta Devi',
 },
 {
  ID: 2,
  Name: 'Cakes & Bakes',
  Author: 'by Sanjeev Kapoor'
 },
 {
  ID: 3,
  Name: 'Jamie’s Kitchen',
  Author: 'by Jamie Oliver'
 },

перед 

class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   AllBooks: props.books,
   filteredBooks: props.books,
  }
 };

далее идут фильтры, все как Вы описывали

после

Comment: <Nav action
      showAllBooks={this.showAllBooks}
      filterByName={this.filterByName}
      filterByAuthor={this.filterByAuthor}
    />



в компоненте General я прописваю

class General extends React.Component {

 render() {
  return (
   <div className="general">
    {this.props.filteredBooks.map((index, key) =>
     <div>
     </div>
    )}
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default General;

Comment: так наверное лучше будет

https://codepen.io/and-1991/pen/dwMXpg

Comment: @ЮрийКоролик  вы не передаете через `props` ваши `books`, напишите так: `this.state = {
   AllBooks: books,
   filteredBooks: books,
  }`. Вы забыли сделать `bind` методов в конструкторе (вот так: `this.filterByName = this.filterByName.bind(this);`), также вы не соблюдаете регистр букв в переменных - это важно (`AllBooks` и `allBooks` - разные переменные). Достаточно много замечаний по коду, будьте внимательны.

Comment: Спасибо огромное Вам. Я посидел пару часиков....пару пару часиков и разобрался. все работает:)))